# Why does SQL Server Image data type have max_length set to 16 in sys.all_columns

Tags: sql-server, metadata

While checking the column definition in SQL Server via SYS.all_columns, I found that the max_length of image data type is set as 16. Can anyone help explain the meaning of this?

Comment: "ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them."  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: It’s the size of the pointer to the LOB value. But who cares? Like Mitch said, you should have stopped using that type 20 years ago. Please read: https://sqlperformance.com/2021/07/sql-performance/deprecated-features-3

Comment: Many people considering the `image` data type are new to SQL Server and probably wanting to store pictures in a database. Firstly... don't do that (store references to pictures in the database, but store the picture content online or in the file system). But if you absolutely must store them in the database use the `varbinary(max)` data type instead.

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes, definitely should avoid image in new project. I am looking at a system built a couple of years ago and cross this 16 max_length for image data type.
@AaronBertrand, thanks for pointing out 16 bytes for pointer length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 16 you see there does not refer to the max size of the *data*, it refers to the size of the *pointer* to the LOB value (which by default is stored off-row).

The [documentation for `sys.columns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql) mentions the 16 bytes, but does a poor job of explaining why (and it only says it applies to `text` but in fact it applies to `text`, `ntext`, and `image`). I recently submitted a PR to make this more clear, and [it was approved](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/pull/6969) (should publish next week or so).

There is a much better little info nugget on [the `TEXTPTR` topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/text-and-image-functions-textptr-transact-sql), where one of the examples says:

> returns the 16-byte text pointer

Note that the [documentation for `image`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql) has had this warning since SQL Server 2005 was released more than 16 years ago:

> IMPORTANT! ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

I also blogged about this just a few months ago:

- [Deprecated features to take out of your toolbox – Part 3](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/07/sql-performance/deprecated-features-3)